# What is `_router` in express?

Tags: express

I'm new to express and often see the code like this:

```
app.once('mount',function onmount(parent){
    parent._router.stack.pop();
});
```

Not sure what is `_router` and why they `pop` it? Any reasons behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mount event occurs when a sub-app is registered with a parent app.  The `parent` argument is the parent app object.

`parent._router` is the router associated with that parent app object.

`parent._router.stack` is the array of routes registered with that route.

`parent._router.stack.pop()` is removing the last registered route from that router.

There isn't enough context here for us to know why that last route is being removed.  It's possible they are trying to remove the 404 error route (just a guess).

FYI, this direct manipulation of private instance variables is not documented behavior.

Comment: Wow thanks, so when you mean by `sub-app` and `parent` app, you are saying like usage of one express instance onto another? Something like `app.use(express())` ?

Comment: @batman - Yeah, it's possible to nest one express app inside another.  It's very much like just using a router in an express app, except that you get a whole app object instead of just a router object.